# How to draw lines on webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a way to draw lines on a ASP.Net webform?

My goal is to visually represent angles. The angles don't have to be exact, but somewhat dynamic.

Is there a .Net control that can do this?

Comment: You could either generate a picture dynamically on the server using Bitmap and Graphics, then have it displayed on a Web Form using a picture, or use a HTML5 Canvas control on the client side and play with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Web Controls, at least the ones shipped with VS are not capable of doing this. In general you can do this on [HTML5 + Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp) or some other third party control.

Another alternative (one that I dislike, BTW) would be to dynamically generate images and streaming them to the browser. But again, that doesn't seem the best option to me.

Answer (score 1):

1 You can use this code based on `DrawLine`

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 200);
graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, 200, 200);
```

2 You can use html tag `<hr />`

3 You can use `jsdraw2d` library

Link : http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/